# How to call ajax function in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one page from where I am adding a question, this page has two select tags, one is to show the types and another is for chapters.

Now while adding question first time user will select a type and then chapters will be loaded through ajax function and will be displayed  in the select tag.

Now when user will submit the form I am saving this type in a session,so that when next time user will go to that page the type will be selected by default.

And now only I can see the type selected in select tag, but nothing in the chapters tag, I want to show the chapters if the type is saved in a session, for that I need to call the ajax function when the page loads and the session type is set.

```
   <?php 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MCQ Questions</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
?>

<form method="post" action="uploadQuestion.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p> Enter the question :</p> <input name="question" type="text"> <br><br>


    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['quetype']))
    {
    $type = $_SESSION["quetype"]; ?>


    Select Rank :
    <select name="types" id="types" onchange="getValue(this)">

        <option value=""> Select Rank</option>

        <option name="type" id="t1" value="1" <?=($type==1?"selected":"");?>> Apprentice </option>

        <option name="type" id="t2" value="2" <?=($type==2?"selected":"");?>> Volume 1 CDC </option>

        <option name="type" id="t3" value="3" <?=($type==3?"selected":"");?>> Volume 2 CDC Video</option>

        <option name="type" id="t4" value="4" <?=($type==4?"selected":"");?>> Volume 3 CDC Video</option>

        <option name="type" id="t5" value="5" <?=($type==5?"selected":"");?>> Volume 4 CDC Video</option>

        <option name="type" id="t6" value="6" <?=($type==6?"selected":"");?>> Volume 5 CDC</option>

        </select> <br><br>

            <?php
            }
            else {
                ?>

                Select Rank :
                <select name="types" id="types" onchange="getValue(this)">

                <option value=""> Select Rank</option>

                    <option name="type" id="t1" value="1"> Apprentice </option>
                    <option name="type" id="t2" value="2"> Volume 1 CDC </option>
                    <option name="type" id="t3" value="3"> Volume 2 CDC Video </option>
                    <option name="type" id="t4" value="4"> Volume 3 CDC Video </option>
                    <option name="type" id="t5" value="5"> Volume 4 CDC Video </option>
                    <option name="type" id="t6" value="6"> Volume 5 CDC </option>

                </select> <br><br>
                <?php
            }
    ?>

    Select chapter :
    <select name="chapters" id="chapters">

     <option value="">Select chapter</option>


    </select> <br><br>

    <p> Enter options :</p>
    Enter option A : <input name="opt1" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option B : <input name="opt2" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option C : <input name="opt3" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option D : <input name="opt4" type="text"> <br><br>

    Select correct answer :

    <select name="ans" id="type">
        <option value="">Select answer...</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value = "Submit">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    <?php

            if(!empty($type))
            {
                ?>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        getValue(<?php echo $type?>);
    });
    <?php

    }


      ?>


        function getValue(obj) {
            var value = obj.value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'edit.php',
                data: {
                    "val" : value
                },
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    //  alert(result);

                    $('#chapters').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to call the function in a script tag in document.ready event, but it did not work. Please help , thank you.

Comment: I don't see you closing PHP tag after these lines. `getValue(<?php echo $type?>); }   <?php }`. You're also not closing the `$(document).ready` properly. Might want to double to check your code. There seems to be a lot of issues with it already.

Comment: Try fixing the two issues I mentioned. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: fixed two issues still its not working.Please check edited code in script tag. I am not getting any error.@cosmoonot

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.   getting this warning in console. @cosmoonot

Comment: To avoid this warning, remove `async: false,`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142563/discussion-between-cosmoonot-and-sid).

Comment: you can use this. working fine ! function getBookDetails(id){
 $.ajax({
         method:'POST',
         url: "orders/bookdetail",
         data: {'book_id': b},
         dataType:'html',
         success: function (response)
     {
      myObj = JSON.parse(response);
      var rate = myObj.rate;
      $('#rate'+id).val(rate);
      $('#amount'+id).val(rate * $('#quantity'+id).val());
     }
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution it may help you in solving your purpose.
This code will not run here as this includes `php` code. Please try to run in your server.

Thanks

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#types').change(function(){
            var value = jQuery(this).val();
            getValue(value);
        });
        console.log(<?php echo $type; ?>);
       if(<?php echo !empty($type) ?>)
        {
            getValue('<?php echo $type?>');
            function getValue(obj){
                var value = obj.value;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'edit.php',
                    data: {
                        "val" : value
                    },
                    dataType: 'text',
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {

                        //  alert(result);

                        jQuery('#chapters').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MCQ Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<form method="post" action="uploadQuestion.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p> Enter the question :</p> <input name="question" type="text"> <br><br>
    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['quetype']))
    {
        echo $type = $_SESSION["quetype"]; ?>
        Select Rank :
        <select name="types" id="types">
            <option value=""> Select Rank</option>
            <option name="type" id="t1" value="1" <?=($type==1?"selected":"");?>> Apprentice </option>
            <option name="type" id="t2" value="2" <?=($type==2?"selected":"");?>> Volume 1 CDC </option>
            <option name="type" id="t3" value="3" <?=($type==3?"selected":"");?>> Volume 2 CDC Video</option>
            <option name="type" id="t4" value="4" <?=($type==4?"selected":"");?>> Volume 3 CDC Video</option>
            <option name="type" id="t5" value="5" <?=($type==5?"selected":"");?>> Volume 4 CDC Video</option>
            <option name="type" id="t6" value="6" <?=($type==6?"selected":"");?>> Volume 5 CDC</option>
        </select> <br><br>
    <?php
    }
    else {
    ?>

        Select Rank :
        <select name="types" id="types" onchange="getValue(this)">
        <option value=""> Select Rank</option>
            <option name="type" id="t1" value="1"> Apprentice </option>
            <option name="type" id="t2" value="2"> Volume 1 CDC </option>
            <option name="type" id="t3" value="3"> Volume 2 CDC Video </option>
            <option name="type" id="t4" value="4"> Volume 3 CDC Video </option>
            <option name="type" id="t5" value="5"> Volume 4 CDC Video </option>
            <option name="type" id="t6" value="6"> Volume 5 CDC </option>
        </select> <br><br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    Select chapter :
    <select name="chapters" id="chapters">
        <option value="">Select chapter</option>
    </select> <br><br>
    <p> Enter options :</p>
    Enter option A : <input name="opt1" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option B : <input name="opt2" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option C : <input name="opt3" type="text"> <br><br>
    Enter option D : <input name="opt4" type="text"> <br><br>
    Select correct answer :
    <select name="ans" id="type">
        <option value="">Select answer...</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what  have you done in this? could u please explain?

Comment: so you are getting the value in $type . i used the document ready function and inside that i check if the $type is empty or not and then called the function for ajax call

Comment: I do not only want to call ajax function once when I have value in type, it will be called on change of option from select tag of types as well

Comment: Ok let me check for the same Give me some time

Comment: please check the updated code for the same. there is change in html where i removed the onchage function and i have added on jquery function